# Referring to outer this from object within class

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a class that has many methods that 'count' stuff, and many methods that 'convert' stuff.

In principal something like this:

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.x = 1
        this.y = 2
        this.cows = ["cow", "cow", "cow"]
        this.horses = ["horse", "horse"]
    }

    convert_x_to_y() {
        return this.x + 1
    }

    convert_y_to_x() {
        return this.y - 1
    }

    count_cows() {
        return this.cows.length
    }

    count_horses() {
        return this.horses.length
    }

}
```

For simplicity, I would like to consolidate all the count functions under a single namespace, and the same for the convert functions.

So instead of `foo.count_cows()` I'd like to have `foo.count.cows()` such that `foo.count` exposes all the counting functions and `foo.convert` exposes all of the conversion functions.

The problem is that when I make an object inside of Foo, `this` no longer refers to Foo.

As such, this does not work because `this` references the inner objects rather than their parent.

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.x = 1
        this.y = 2
        this.cows = ["cow", "cow", "cow"]
        this.horses = ["horse", "horse"]
    }
    convert = {
        x_to_y () {
            return this.x + 1    
        },
        y_to_x () {
            return this.y - 1    
        }
    }

    count = {
        cows () {
            return this.cows.length
        },
        horses () {
            return this.horses.length
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve my goal of name-spacing the methods without breaking the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) so that your functions don't have their own `this`, but rather take the `this` of the context they're defined in. Note that I've moved your [public field declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Field_declarations) on your class inside the constructor for better browser support (as public field declarations are currently stage 3)

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.x = 1
    this.y = 2
    this.cows = ["cow", "cow", "cow"];
    this.horses = ["horse", "horse"];

    this.convert = {
      x_to_y: () => this.x + 1,
      y_to_x: () => this.y - 1
    }
    this.count = {
      cows: () => this.cows.length, // arrow function without body (implict return)
      horses: () => { // arrow function with body (explicitly state return)
        return this.horses.length
      }
    }
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.count.cows());
console.log(foo.count.horses());
```

Comment: I love this solution. This is running on a Node.js app, so browser support is not an issue, but I'll adopt your edit regardless. Thanks!

Comment: No worries! Public field declarations should be fine to use if it's a nodejs environment